# Who picks the type of the Basic Attack when this power is used?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

Charm of Misplaced Wrath (Heroes of Fallen Lands, p. 206) reads:

> The target makes a **basic attack** against a creature of your choice as a free action. The basic attack gains a +2 power bonus to the damage roll.

This is a 1st level Wizard encounter power, if it matters.

**Can *I* make the target do a *Ranged* Basic Attack (so it provokes attacks of opportunity) or does *the target* get to pick the type of Basic Attack?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would claim that RAW it is up to the target what kind of attack it uses. The spell description specifies that you get to choose the target but not what kind of (basic) attack it uses. Reasonably the target would use the (basic) attack it is most proficient with or the (basic) attack that best suits the situation.

There doesn't seem to be any clear consensus on the matter though. I found [this](https://www.enworld.org/threads/charm-of-misplaced-wrath.271566/) and [this](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?473585-Simple-Q-amp-A-D-amp-D-4e-Thread-3/page9) thread on other forums that discusses it. In the end the ruling would be up to the DM I guess.

Answer (score 1):

### The basic attack is not "of your choice", so the target gets to choose.

You could force the issue if the power hit and you slid the target away from the creature you wanted it to attack, assuming you've still got allies in position.